# Regex to match a local filename but not its absolute file path

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regex in Java to match the local filename ending with .abc
The input should not match the absolute path since a malicious user can put ../../ in the file path and refer to another file

I currently have `"^[^(\\.+|/+)](.+?)(\\.abc$)"`  which basically makes sure its not beginning with any .. or / and is ending with .abc. But i need to improve it to make sure we can't add .. and / in the middle of the input as well. Any ideas would help , I want to update the same regex

These are unix paths

Comment: What are you starting with? If you've got a `File`, `Path` or any other java object, then you can skip this step. You can apply your regex to the local name as returned by those classes. If not, then you can create one of those objects from your string, and get the local name from that.

Comment: Makes sense ! yeah my input is a string and your solution pretty cleverly sanitizes my path. Thanks Paul!